# IAsyncOperation<StoreProductResult> не содержит определения для GetAwaiter

Tags: c#, xamarin

Есть проект на Xamarin Forms на .net standart 2.0.
В общем проекте объявлен интерфейс:

```
public interface IIAPService
{
    Task<string> GetAppInfoAsync();
}
```

При его реализации в проекте для UWP(пример взят из с сайта Microsoft:

```
public class IAPService : IIAPService
{
    private StoreContext context = null;

    public IAPService() { }

    public async Task<string> GetAppInfoAsync()
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
            // If your app is a desktop app that uses the Desktop Bridge, you
            // may need additional code to configure the StoreContext object.
            // For more info, see https://aka.ms/storecontext-for-desktop.
        }

        // Get app store product details. Because this might take several moments,   
        // display a ProgressRing during the operation.
        StoreProductResult queryResult = await context.GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync();

        if (queryResult.Product == null)
        {
            // The Store catalog returned an unexpected result.
            //textBlock.Text = "Something went wrong, and the product was not returned.";

            // Show additional error info if it is available.
            if (queryResult.ExtendedError != null)
            {
                //textBlock.Text += $"\nExtendedError: {queryResult.ExtendedError.Message}";
            }

            return;
        }

        // Display the price of the app.
        //textBlock.Text = $"The price of this app is: {queryResult.Product.Price.FormattedBasePrice}";
    }
}
```

Появляется ошибка:`Ошибка   CS4036  'IAsyncOperation<StoreProductResult>" не содержит определения для "GetAwaiter", и не удалось найти метод расширения "GetAwaiter", принимающий тип "IAsyncOperation<StoreProductResult>" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using для "System").`

С помощью Google нашел только одно решение: использовать .net framework 4.5 вместо 4.0, но дело в том, что я использую .net standart 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [`GetAwaiter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582011(v=vs.110).aspx) определен в классе [`System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions(v=vs.110).aspx) сборки `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`.

Проверьте что у вас подключена эта сборка и что в начале файла есть директива `using System;`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Отсутствовала директива `using System`. Странно, что Intellisense не сработала в этом случае. Спасли меня от переустановки студии)

Comment: Intellisense не сработала, потому что это метод расширения и GetAwaiter здесь вызывается неявно, @Emigrant